# Pyinstaller app yields error OS status -67062 for unidentified developers (just OSX High Sierra)

Tags: pyinstaller, macos-high-sierra, osx-gatekeeper

Tested on OSX High Sierra 10.13.2

I have packaged a .app on my Mac (High Sierra 10.12.6) using Pyinstaller 3.2. The app works fine on my computers, as well as on Windows. Before High Sierra, I had no trouble distributing to Mac users. I am not a Mac identified developer, so users have to bypass the gateway using "Open Anyways" described [here](http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/08/bypass-gatekeeper-mac-os-x-security-prefs/).

After users upgrade to high sierra, then go through the regular process to "Open Anyways" to override unidentified developer error, but then they are given the unusual error (in spanish in this user case).

Translated:

Could not complete the operation OSStatus -67062.

[image]

[Here](http://[http://www.clemensprescher.com/programs/dioptas/dioptas-faq][3]) is one workaround that works, but is pretty intense for the average user.

High Sierra users need to temporarily disable GateKeeper.

`sudo spctl --master-disable`

<strike>open the app by double clicking.</strike>

Open the app in the command line once

```
open -a "DeepMeerkat"
```

and then you can go back and re-enable GateKeeper.

`sudo spctl --master-enable`

I've tested this and it works. But this is awkward, and obviously suboptimal. I'm considering it only a workaround until a true fix arrives.

Is there something that can be done or is Apple really clamping down on us not paying the 100$/year license?

My .app is just self-signed, which used to be enough for gatekeeper

```
MacBook-Pro:Mac ben$ codesign -dv dist/DeepMeerkat.app
Executable=/Users/ben/Documents/DeepMeerkat/Installer/Mac/dist/DeepMeerkat.app/Contents/MacOS/main
Identifier=DeepMeerkat
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=98748 flags=0x0(none) hashes=3081+3 location=embedded
Signature size=1948
Signed Time=Jan 25, 2018, 11:35:33 AM
Info.plist entries=9
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=1633
Internal requirements count=1 size=88
```